# Requisição do tipo Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, html5, node.js

Minha duvida é, sempre que faço uma requisição antes dela ser realmente enviando uma requisição do tipo Options é enviada, queria saber pra que exatamente serve. Qual o impacto que posso ter ao retirar esta requisição tanto no desempenho(internet) tanto em questões de segurança. Como eu faço para somente mandar a requisição sem este Options antes ?
Requisição Options:
[image: Requisição Options]

Requisição que realmente quero: 
[image: Requisição POST]

Comment: Já tive esse problema algumas vezes. Corrigi no meu caso, acrescentando headers como contente-type na requisição. Pode ser que funcione para você...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Angular respeita a especificação de comportamento no caso de requisição HTTP de recursos entre origens (do inglês [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS), ou Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

Uma destas especificações determina a necessidade de uma requisição inicial ([preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)) que informa a disponibilidade, ou não, de recursos: Esta é a requisição OPTIONS.

Um retorno típico de uma requisição OPTIONS se parece com o trecho a seguir:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:15:39 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400 
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 0 
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Content-Type: text/plain
```

O cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` indica um ou mais domínios de origem aceitos.
O cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` informa os verbos possíveis. No exemplo acima não é possível utilizar PATCH e DELETE, por exemplo.
Uma lista de cabeçalhos aceitáveis pode ser indicada via `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.O método HTTP OPTIONS é utilizado para que um cliente possa descobrir quais as opções de requisição permitidas para um determinado recurso em um servidor. O cliente pode especificar uma URL específica no método OPTIONS ou um asterisco(*) indicando que se refere ao servidor como um todo para sanar suas dúvidas em relação as opções de requisição permitidas.